# How to set the slected value of a combo box residing in a usercontrol from parent page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, webforms

I have a parent page containing a usercontrol. The usercontrol has several comboboxes and textboxes. The comboboxes are populated during page_load event of the usercontrol. I want to set values of these controls from the parent page. In the usercontrol I have a public method to which I pass the data and setting the values as shown below. It works fine for textboxes. But the comboboxes don't show the selected value. I think it is because the page lifecycle and the comboboxes's selected values are set after the page_load event of the usercontrol. Please let me know the best way of showing the selected value of the comboboxes.

The following is the public method in UC which I call from the parent page and pass data.

```
public void PopulateControlsForEdit(MemberMaintenanceData memberData, EmployeeType type)
```

{

```
      FirstNameTextBox.Text = memberData.FirstName;
      cboState.SelectedIndex = cboState.Items.IndexOf(cboState.Items.FindByValue(memberData.State));
```

}

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this for setting the selected item:

```
cboState.SelectedItem.Selected = false;
cboState.Items.FindByValue(memberData.State).Selected = true;
```